# How can I add animation or smooth scrolling in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, scroll, carousel

I'm using the following code to create a carousel effect. By pressing the DOM elements the wrapper is scrolled back or forth based on which button is pressed.

```
next.addEventListener("click", function(){
document.querySelector(".carouselWrapper").scrollLeft += 1260;
});

prev.addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector(".carouselWrapper").scrollLeft -= 1260;
});
```

The problem is the scroll is instant, and hardly a pleasurable experience. What's the simplest way to make some sort of transition slide, or even a fade-in to the next "slide"?

Answer (score 0):

### CSS Transitions

You can use **CSS Transitions** to obtain automatic animation.

```
.carouselWrapper{
   transition: left 2s;
}
```

For more details about Transitions you can read the [Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions)

**However, you probably will need to make some changes on your HTML wrapping code.**
Check the following implementation :

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById("carouselInner");

document.getElementById("next").onclick = function(){
    wrapper.style.left = ( wrapper.offsetLeft - 55  ) + 'px';
}
```

```css
#carouselOutter{
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}    
#carouselInner{
  transition: left 1s;
  left:0px;
  position:absolute;
}
#carouselInner>div{
  background:blue;
  padding:20px;
  float:left;
  margin-right:5px;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div id="carouselOutter">
  <div id="carouselInner">
    <div>1</div> <div>2</div> <div>3</div> <div>4</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="next">Next</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

JS:

```
next.addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector(".carouselWrapper").style.left += 1260;
});

prev.addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector(".carouselWrapper").style.left -= 1260;
});
```

CSS:

```
.carouselWrapper {
    transition: left 0.5s ease-out
}
```